# Water damage to outside wall

Tags: walls

In an outside wall at an entrance door the bottom plate and studs for the door frame, sheathing and possibly the wall studs have rotted from water leaking in from a space between the aluminum siding and concrete porch.  I planned on putting in a pressure treated bottom plate and caulking the gap outside.  Should I attach a small sister studs or build up the bottom plate to meet the existing studs?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram would really help us understand your question.

Comment: Yeah, can you at least take a picture. I'm assuming the concrete porch is below the door threshold. In that case, how did it rot the door frame? Is it more likely the water got in through the door opening? You probably need flashing between the sheathing and the concrete porch too.